# clearContent is not working in conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to record the date value in Column B when there is a new string data in Column A.
When the data in Column A is deleted, the date value in Column B is also cleared.

Here is the script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();   
    s.getName() == "SheetName";    
  var r = s.getActiveCell();   
    r.getColumn() == 1 ;
  if (r != null) {  
    var check = r.offset(0, 1);
      check.setNumberFormat("MM/dd") ;
      check.setValue(new Date());
     }
  if (r == null) {  
    check.clearContents();
     }

}
```

The first part of the code works fine, however I cannot manage to clear the value once the data in Column A is deleted.

Please help me with the code correction. Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: About `I want to record the date value in Column B when there is a new string data in Column A. When the data in Column A is deleted, the date value in Column B is also cleared.`, when I saw your showing script, in this case, when a value is put into column "A" of "SheetName" sheet, it seems that the value of `new Date()` is put into column "F". But, you say `The first part of the code works fine`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this? Or, do you want to put `new Date()` into column "F"? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, yes I intended to put it into Column B. I corrected the error. Please help me with the clearContents issue. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a value is put into column "A", you want to put `new Date()` to column "B" of the same row.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `r` of `var r = s.getActiveCell()` is Class Range. In this case, even when the value of the active cell is both empty and not empty, `r == null` is not true. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

  - In this case, I thought that [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank) might be able to be used.
- `s.getName() == "SheetName";` and `r.getColumn() == 1;` are not used in the script.
- In your showing script, it seems that the event object is not used. Do you want to also directly run the script with the script editor?

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, the event object is not used. Please replace `"Sheet1"` with your actual sheet name.

```js
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1") return;
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (range.getColumn() != 1) return;
  var colB = range.offset(0, 1);
  if (range.isBlank()) {
    colB.clearContent();
  } else {
    colB.setNumberFormat("MM/dd").setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

- In this modification, when a value is put into column "A" of "Sheet1", `new Date()` is put into column "B" of the same row. When the cell value of column "A" is cleared, the cell value of column "B" is also cleared.
- This script can be run with both the script editor and the simple trigger.

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, the event object is used. Please replace `"Sheet1"` with your actual sheet name.

```js
function onEdit({ range }) {
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || range.columnStart != 1) return;
  var colB = range.offset(0, 1);
  if (range.isBlank()) {
    colB.clearContent();
  } else {
    colB.setNumberFormat("MM/dd").setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

- In this modification, when a value is put into column "A" of "Sheet1", `new Date()` is put into column "B" of the same row. When the cell value of column "A" is cleared, the cell value of column "B" is also cleared.
- This script can be run with a simple trigger. When you directly run this function, an error like `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.` occurs because of no event object. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I really appreciate your detailed and begginer friendly explanation. The code works perfectly. It helps a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

clearContents in  a method of  Class Sheet and clearContent is a method of Class Range. check is an instance of Class Range.

So remove the s from the end of clearContents and it will work.

- [Range.clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)